# Changing color of objects not working, can't see materials in viewport

Tags: edit-mode

I am having trouble changing colors of objects.

I've changed the color of the material but it isn't making any visible changes and preview is unchanged in the viewport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are now in *Solid view*, where materials don't appear.
Switch to *Material Preview* or *Rendered preview*, and your colors will be there.

[image]

You can also set a color for Solid view only, in *Material > Viewport display* options.

[image]

Comment: AWSOME....got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting keyframes for the object color if you want to change the color during the animation. Your current view is solid, so the color is not going to change unless you go to rendered view.

Comment: it is supposed to change in rendered mode.

Comment: There is no animation yet, just the text. I am going to make another video to better clarify, I am doing things wrong and I can't figure out what. Will be a minute, have to let the dogs out.