# Trying to color Text

Tags: color

So I created the text with the add text button - I'm using version 2.91 - then I went to the right tab with all the properties functions: world properties, materials properties, physics properties, etc., then I extruded the text a bit(stretched it).

Next, I went to the materials tab to color it, clicked on new , the sphere showed up, then I clicked on the color line(base color) and chose a color, but nothing happened to the text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing color of objects not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161376/changing-color-of-objects-not-working)

Comment: Related: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to switch preview modes. Press Z in the 3D viewport and pick either "Material Preview" or "Rendered" from the pie menu.  The Preview Modes and Viewport Shading Options can also be accessed from the 4 circles and the little down arrow, respectively, at the top right of the viewport:

[image: Previews]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on Render preview or material preview tab

[image]